# Combine two different filter callback functions

Tags: functions

I am currently using this code which works fine.

```
function add_data_attribute($tag, $handle) {
   if ( 'chargebee' !== $handle )
    return $tag;
    return str_replace( ' src', ' data-cb-site="mydomain" src', $tag );
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_data_attribute', 10, 2);
```

However I need to combine this code with another tag:

```
function google_maps_script_attributes( $tag, $handle) {
    if ( 'google-maps' !== $handle ) {
        return $tag;
  }
    return str_replace( ' src', ' async="async" defer src', $tag );
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'google_maps_script_attributes', 10, 2);
```

Should I call two separate functions as best practice, or is it faster and better to combine the two functions together somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could or even should combine your filters to keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', function( $tag, $handle ) {

 if ( 'chargebee' == $handle ) :
    return str_replace( ' src', ' data-cb-site="mydomain" src', $tag );
 elseif( 'google-maps' == $handle ) :
    return str_replace( ' src', ' async="async" defer src', $tag );
 endif;

 return $tag;

}, 10, 2);
```